# How to get only specified object class from mongo collection with spring data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I write two classes in one mongo collection, say One and Two. In these classes I have field someId. Then I want to get all One objects with specified someId. I created a method:

```
Page<One> findBySomeId(String id, Pageable pageable);
```

But get error:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate ...

As I see, mongo take both One and Two objects, and then trying to create One objects from them.
I tried write next:

```
Page<One> findOneBySomeId(String id, Pageable pageable);
```

and got the same error. How to write a proper method to retrieve only specified objects from mongo DB with spring data?

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be like this

```
Page<IOne> findByOneSomeId(String id, Pageable pageable);

public interface IOne {

    public One getOne();

}
```

Comment: Instead of 'Page<One>' we can get it in a list i.e 'List<One>'.

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the query by specifying something that distinguishes `One` and `Two`. For example, you can filter by:

- the (internal) `_type` field that spring automatically persist, which is equal to the fully qualified class name (unless `@TypeAlias` is provided, when it could be whatever you set)
- some other property that you know is present only in the `One` documents (`Page<One> findBySomeIdAndPropertyExistsTrue(String id, Pageable pageable)`)

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Data you can use following syntax :

```
One findFirstBySomeId(String someId);
```

Here is documentation about spring data(4.4.5. Limiting Query Results) where you find the explanation and examples: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference